# How to pass a custom logo image and user note in PayPal API billing-agreements/agreement-tokens

Tags: paypal

How to pass a custom logo image and user note in PayPal API billing-agreements/agreement-tokens ? The same can be passed in payment API using "experience_profile_id" parameter

Answer (score 0):

Found it out. This is available in the new PayPal Reference transactions / pre-approved payments API. It shoule be passed as experience_id under merchant_preferences . the experience id can be created from here[Experience Profile](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payment-experience/v1/).  .  Docs are available here[PayPal docs Rest API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/limited-release/reference-transactions/api/#definition-merchant_preferences)